# Append date and time to branch name when creating new branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to append datetime to branch name if the branch name is a specific word like `kirkversion`? The use case is related to a script that runs on the server and looks for branch name `kirkversion` to do a couple of extra steps. And perhaps the user creating the branch?

```
git checkout -b kirkversion
```

would create a branch named `kirkversion20201910203049` or `kirkversion20201910203049username`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)** You can't do this with `git checkout` or `git branch` or `git switch` itself, but you can, very easily, run a bit of shell code that *generates the name*.

**(2)** Try

```
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

produces the current year-month-day-hour(24-hour-format)-minute-second `20201125083255`

**(3)** Characters that are not percent signs are copied literally

```
date +kirkversion%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

becomes `kirkversion20201125083344` . (note that the minutes and seconds have changed).

**(4)** Use this in `sh/bash`, you would simply embed the output of the `date` command into the `git checkout -b` command

```
git checkout -b $(date +kirkversion%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```